# Where is the Live Trace function in Adobe Illustrator CC?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, live-trace

[image]

I want to change the color of this MailChimp logo (png file) in Adobe Illustrator CC. I've looked in Adobe Forums and Youtube, all mentioned Live Trace, but I don't have that option in Object on the nav bar. So I have two questions...

1. Is Live Trace removed in Adobe Illustrator CC?
2. How can I change the colors of this logo?

Please help! Thank you.

Comment: CS5 (or older) Live Trace = Image Trace in CS6 (or newer) -- Without Tracing, Illustrator is not the correct tool to alter the colors of a PNG file. Use Photoshop. I'd also hazard a guess that tracing that isn't going to yield *excellent* results.

Comment: you don't have to re-trace it again. you can simply download it as a vector graphics from this [link](http://mailchimp.com/about/brand-assets/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, live trace is available in Illustrator CC, it's called image trace.

Follow these steps to change color of the chimp.

1. First select the image then select image trace in the tools option bar.

[image]

2. click the down arrow next to image trace and select 16 colors.
3. Select expand.
4. Now right click the object and choose ungroup. (ctrl + shift + G)
5. Now you can select different parts of the chimp's face and change colours.